# How to mount file system without root access using C program?

Tags: c, unix, exec, mount

I am facing one problem. My requirement is, I need to mount `NFS` directory as a normal user. I don't want to use `root`. For that, I have developed the below simple program to achieve this. But, It is not working as expected.

My program :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void usage( char *progName ) {
        printf("Usage : %s {mount|umount}\n",progName);
}

int main( char argc , char *argv[] )
{
        if ( argc != 2 ) {
                usage( argv[0] );
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if ( strcmp(argv[1] , "mount") == 0 ) {
                execlp("mount", "mount", "192.168.12.3:/home/share", "/home/share", NULL);
        }
        else if( strcmp(argv[1] , "umount" ) == 0 ) {
                execlp("umount", "umount", "/home/share", NULL);
        }
        else {
                usage( argv[0] );
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then,

```
$ cc mount_share.c -o Mount
```

I also set the `set user id` for the executable file.

```
$ chmod u+s Mount
$ ls -lhrt Mount
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root    root    8.3K Jun  4 17:47 Mount
```

Then I executed the `Mount` as a normal user, Still it says error. That is,

```
mount: only root can do that
```

As of my knowledge, It should work.

Can you point out what is wrong with my code?

Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot do that. You might read more about [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) -be careful, mistakes could open huge security holes!- and you should use commands like `sudo` or `super` (and you could configure them carefully to avoid asking any passwords for some *selected* commands)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I am looking for a solution like how `passwd` command is working.

Comment: I downvoted, because it is a fairly common question (and probably has been asked here many times in different forms). Also, because you did not explain why do you want to do that (why don't you use `sudo`, why do you fork a `mount` command and not use the [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) syscall, etc...). The question has a lot of answers, is poorly asked and not motivated enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuDo is specially designed for this purpose - to allow unprivileged users run privileged command(to delegate authority).
In order to solve your problem you have to add `setuid(0);`, before attempting to `execlp(3)`

Comment: Thank you..But, I don't want to use `sudo`. I would like to use my knowledge `(setuid+exec+other)` to achieve this.

Comment: +1, thank you. You solved my problem. But, I would like to know the difference between `chmod u+s Mount` and `setuid(0)` calling inside the program.

Comment: @Kalanidhi try to read POSIX documentation - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html , RATIONALE section .

Answer (score 3):

As user1641854 said you could use `sudo`.  If you don't want to do that you could also add the expected mount point to `/etc/fstab` and make sure it has the `user` flag set to allow non-root users to mount it

Something like:

```
192.168.12.3:/home/share /home/share nfs user
```

though you may want other flags as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is quite wrong in practice: use `sudo` or `super` (or call [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) syscall directly, which is tricky for NFS mounts).

You should change (to `root`, i.e. 0) both the real and the effective uid before `execlp`, using [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)

Notice that the *setuid* flag on the executable file enables your program to `setreuid` (or to call `setuid`), but does not do that automatically (because your program could do some few things -as the ordinary user- *before* calling `setreuid`, e.g. open some configuration file to be readable by the ordinary user running your command)

See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)